# Can you say "focused to" (topics)

Tags: prepositions

Use of *to* after the word *focused*.

Can you say ***focused to*** (something) or do you always have to say ***focused on*** (something)?

Comment: There's only one s in "focused"... I can edit your question but not your username...

Comment: @Catija there are two recognis/zed spellings of [focussed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/focused) and see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/focussed)

Comment: *The spelling focused is much more common in the US but also more common in the UK and Australia.* @Mari-LouA https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/focussed

Comment: @Catija  But it is still acceptable in BrEng, and you were wrong to say it was misspelled. Likewise, it would be wrong for me to say that word should be spelt misspelt.

Comment: Could you tell us the entire sentence? Both prepositions are acceptable in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

**Focused on** is standard, but I have heard **focused toward**. Personally, I'd not use the latter

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible!* Though you don't see this everywhere, every time!

COCA brings 68 results of the usage *focused to...* but you need to carefully look at the ***context*** before using it.

The simplest one from there that I liked is:

> Stay ***focused to*** get ahead.

Google Ngram also shows results, for instance, the Oxford Textbook of Ophthalmology has the usage

> Rays from a point P near one end of the filament are ***focused to*** a diffraction broadened spot on the screen.